# How do instances of Andrej Karpathy's BigramLanguageModel run as functions with no `__call__` function?

Tags: python, call

Andrej Karpathy's nanoGPT defines [`BigramLanguageModel`](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JMLa53HDuA-i7ZBmqV7ZnA3c_fvtXnx-?usp=sharing) as follows.

```
class BigramLanguageModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...

    def forward(self, x):
        ...
```

It then runs the following.

```
m = BigramLanguageModel(vocab_size)
logits, loss = m(xb, yb)
```

The call to `m()` runs the `forward()` method as if there were a `__call__` function that called `forward()`. But no `__call__` function is visible. How does this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `nn.Module` provide a `__call__` that calls `self.forward`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the base class `torch.nn.Module` defines `__call__`. See [the implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v1.13.1/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1238).

The following example shows a similar technique.

```
class X:
    def test(self):
        print('test')
    __call__ = test

X()()
# This will output 'test'.
```

As a side note, you incorrectly scrapped the `__init__()` of the BigramLanguageModel in that Notebook.

Comment: Thanks. That does it. The actual details are a bit messy though.

`__call__ : Callable[..., Any] = _call_impl`  
`_call_impl` includes the line: 
`forward_call = (self._slow_forward if torch._C._get_tracing_state() else self.forward)` and
eventually `return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)`
And this leaves out most of `_call_impl` !